# Giving C++ containers to OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, containers, shader-storage-buffer

I created a shader storage buffer object to give information to my vertex shader. It is bound to a buffer containing a single structure. But there is a problem. The data I keep in this structure is not a simple array, it's a `std::vector`.

Here is the structure :

```
typedef struct {
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
} entityInfo;

typedef struct {
    std::vector<entityInfo> entityInfoBuffer;
} shaderData;
```

mat4 is just a simple 4x4 float matrix.

If I give this to OpenGL, the data transmitted to the GPU will be just a bunch of pointers and info about the matrix/vector, and not the data in them.

One solution would be to create a structure only for OpenGL:

```
typedef struct {
    float* modelMatrix;
} SSBOentityInfo;

typedef struct {
    SSBOentityInfo* entityInfoBuffer;
} SSBOshaderData;
```

But I would have to copy eeeeevery pointer corresponding to the data of the containers.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to just send the contents of `entityInfoBuffer` to the GPU? You don't want to be copying CPU pointers to the GPU, they won't mean anything to the GPU (you might as well be copying random numbers).

Comment: I think that, when using a shader storage buffer object, you have to use structs ? I am wrong ? That would mean I would have to set `entityInfoBuffer.data()` to the SSBOshaderData `entityInfoBuffer` ? Also, OpenGL will only be able to read `&mat4[0][0]`.

Comment: @Talesseed: "*you have to use structs ?*" Why? Data is data, memory is memory, and buffer objects are buffer objects.

Comment: Yes, my bad... I just want to use structs to be able to add elements that I may need after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glm::mat4` is, for all intents and purposes, an array of 16 `float`s. Not a *pointer* to 16 floats, an actual `float[16]` array. 16 `float`s, one after the other.

Therefore, a `vector<glm::mat4>` manages a contiguous array of elements, where each element is 16 floats. It is that data that you want to store in your buffer object. So... do that.

`vector` manages a contiguous array of data, so it's perfectly legal to get a pointer to this array. That's what `vector.data()` is for. So that's the source pointer you give to `glBufferSubData` or whatever. The size would be the number of elements in the array (`vector.size()`) times the size of each element as computed by `sizeof`.

Comment: Thanks, I though that mat4 wasn't an array. However, what can I do if  I want to use structs to be able to add elements later on ?

Comment: @Talesseed: It's not clear what you mean by that, but I'm pretty sure that's a different question from the one you asked here.

Comment: I wanted to add more members to shaderData. But yes, I think that is another question.

Comment: And for the typedef, the second awnser explains that the absence of typedef can lead to a bug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: @Talesseed: That's what *namespaces* are for. Also, it's a bug so rare that most dedicated C++ programmers don't even know its a possibility.